# INSERT table into other table with more columns using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert a database table into another one which has more columns. I need all records of it. What i tried is following which is not working and does not give me an error message:

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table1");

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $sql1 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table2
                                    (uid,
                                    pid,
                                    tstamp,
                                    crdate)
                                   VALUES ('',
                                          '".$row['value1']."',
                                          '".$row['value2']."',
                                          '".$row['value3']."'");}
```

Comment: " Missing at end! it should be );"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can directly do it like this, that's much faster and better than fetching the data and iterating over it.

```
 insert into table2(uid,pid,tstamp,crdate) 
 select value1,value2,value3,value4 from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

you forget close `"` :

```
 mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table2
                                    (uid,
                                    pid,
                                    tstamp,
                                    crdate)
                                   VALUES ('',
                                          '".$row['value1']."',
                                          '".$row['value2']."',
                                          '".$row['value3']."');");
```

also you can do this in query by select into to reduce consuming time:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (uid,pid,tstamp,crdate)
SELECT '',val1,val2,val3 FROM table1;
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i edited my post, actually i closed it before the brackets, because the sql statement also begins in brackets.

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski replace } with )

Comment: check the answer in the last line